# Reading integers from text file, getting min/max - Java

Tags: java

I need to grab the minimum and maximum values from a text file that holds 1,000 integers.  My program is already setup to compute the median and averages of this file.  What I want to do is create a variable `maxValue` to hold the maximum value as it iterates through the text file.  Something like: if maxValue < currentValue; currentValue = maxValue.  I've initialized my variable maxValue to 0, how do I now read in the first value, and compare it?

```
package week2examples;

import java.util.Arrays;<br>
import stdlib.StdIn;<br>
import stdlib.StdOut;

    public class StatisticsArray {

public static double average(int[] numbers) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
        sum += numbers[index];
    }
          }

    return (double)sum/numbers.length;
}


public static double median(int[] numbers) {
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    if (numbers.length % 2 == 0) {
        return (numbers[numbers.length/2]+numbers[numbers.length/2-1])/2.0;
    }
    else {
        return numbers[numbers.length/2];
    }
}

    public static double maximum(int[] numbers) {
    int maxValue = 0;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StdIn.fromFile ("data/1kints.txt");
    int[] numbers = StdIn.readAllInts();

    StdOut.println("The average is " + average(numbers));
    StdOut.println("The median is " + median(numbers));

}
```

Comment: You should try to understand the code before asking such a simple question. Just take a look at the two methods already defined and create the `maximum` method similarly.

Comment: The title is misleading. You know how to take the maximum of several integers already; as far as reading it in can't you just say numbers[0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static double maximum(int[] numbers) {
       int maxValue = 0;
       for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
           if (maxValue < numbers[index]){
              maxValue = numbers[index];
           }
       }
       return maxValue;
    }
```

This is max for min just flip the comparison sign, I'll leave that to you.